# REST Testing for CSRF Enable Website

Tags: security-testing, web-service, rest

I want to perform rest testing, like **strong text** rest client but issue here is website which I am performing testing sets CSRF token in browser in such situation rest client gives `403 error`, is there any alternative way to perform these test(s).

Comment: Are you doing Security testing of this REST service? As you have mentioned the tag 'security-testing', if yes which tool you are using for security testing?

Comment: Your issue of CSRF token will get resolved with the answer mentioned in this question, after that you can proceed with the testing of your REST service. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15388/load-testing-on-csrf-enabled-website-with-jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with burp :

Just make sure that you check Rest style url parameters

[image]

Steps you can do were :

1)intercept the request with proxy of burp

2)Right click navigate to engagement tools -->CSRF poc

3)generate a csrf token with invalid/vulnerable parameters

4)check with browser to get the request

Detailed part can be found [here](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1965674-Methodology_Cross-Site%20Request%20Forgery%20%28CSRF%29.html)